# How to make User silent Activation in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

I need some guidelines or documents to make User silent Activation(directly activate the User without sending the email) through API or UI in DocuSign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silent Activation using API is deprecated now and DocuSign does not allow any DS Accounts to use this in their DS plan. There are two ways to activate the user without send the email, and both ways need that you should claim emaildomain in DocuSign and all the users should belong to this claimed email domain:

a. Using `SSO`, you claim your email domain in the DocuSign and configure your Identity provider with DocuSign, and once SSO is correctly configured then you can activate the user without any emails.

b. A `new feature` added recently, with this feature You need to claim your domain, create an Organization, then there is setting at the domain level (see below snapshot) which you can select to add a user within the claimed email domain without sending an email.

[image]

Comment: After enabling the auto-activate memberships by default,I cannot activate the user without sending email.

Comment: This worked for me. Strange how if someone has already configured SSO, and checked "require all users to authenticate with identity provider," adding new users still sends an email to the user to activate, which asks for a password. Checking the "auto-activate" did bypass that step. Strangely enough, I can still add a user and select "identity provider or username / password" for login policy.